# How to change the background color of EditText without removing the standard bottom border

Tags: android, background

After the call of `EditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)` I see only a red rectangle with text inside it, but I want to change only the text background and to keep the standard bottom border which is grey when the field has no focus and blue if it has focus. Can I do it programmatically?

I want to change the text background to red if the input is invalid and to transparent if it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to work with `drawable/shape.xml` as background and upon logic code situation call `EditText.setBackground(some_other_shape.xml)`. Here is an example for shape file `xml` demonstrating how to use:

1. Border color ("stroke"): In this example some custom color from `colors.xml`
2. Fill color ("solid"): In this example `Android` default transparent color
3. Even image icon inside

   `<!--Example for custom shape file xml design-->
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:drawable="@mipmap/icon_image" />
       <item>
           <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:shape="oval">
               <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
               <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/orange_primary" />
           </shape>
       </item>
   </layer-list>`

So just prepare several shapes for each situation you need. Another approach is to work with `layout params` etc. but I think this one is faster and gives more control for custom design in easy to understand code.

Comment: Do you have any workaround sample for the above solution?